# Can I add a "Create constant" option in Resharper?

Tags: c#, resharper, constants

In resharper, whenever I use an undeclared symbol in code, I can use the red bulb to automatically create it, e.g. something like [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Generation__Generating_Code_from_Usage.html). I often need a create constant option, that will create a const field, but this option doesn't exist in normal resharper. Is it possible to configure it to have this option?

Answer (score 0):

Well without knowing your Resharper version, but at least in 6.1 it is already suggesting a conversion of a variable or field to a constant equivalent, if it's used that way.

[image: example]

Ah I see, my answer is not fully complete. Well, you can create a const variable or field in two steps. First you have to declare it and then you have to convert it to const. I think the reason is simply, that Jet Brains didn't see a 'Create const variable or field' option as normal usecase.

Comment: Is there any way to add this option through Options or something?

Comment: Well, no I guess. IMHO if you think about it's perfectly solved by JetBrains. While writing the code the programmer shall not focus on the character of a variable or field but on the goal he wants to achieve. So he can write code as it comes to his mind. The optimization, cleanup aso. is the next step. This is a perfect job for the Resharper because now it can determine the optimization potential without harming the solution.